# Android Configurating UI Table View

Tags: android

I have integrated the TableView from [here](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview) . The control is very well written, except for a problem that its wrap_content does not work. Either you have to hard code a height of it takes the full height of the parent. Has anyone dealt with this ?

Kind Regards,